# How do I configure multiple domain with same IP but different port?

Tags: dns, domain, hosts

I plan to have several domains and map each domain to the same IP but different port

Example:

```
www.test.com should map to http://119.81.80.218:8888/
www.test2.com should map to http://119.81.80.218:8889/
```

Are the above doable ? How to achieve that ?

Comment: What OS, how many hosts involved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that placing some daemon listening to port `80` which would act as a proxy. A good candidate to be that daemon is `Nginx`.

You can then have several Virtual Hosts (one per domain, or several if they all forward to the same port) having a configuration like this:

```
server {
   listen        80;
   server_name   www.test.com;

   location / {
     proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8888/;
   }
}
```

If some domains resolve to different IPs (and different machines), you could place a `Nginx` daemon on each of them with a similar configuration.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The OP is clearly talking about `HTTP`, my answer refers to domain-name based proxy and it does what they're asking for. So?